# How to get Pricing details of azure resources using API?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

I need to get pricing details for SQL Server and Storage account in my application. I have found this url - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/retail-prices/azure-retail-prices#api-endpoint but this works for Azure Virtual Machines. Will the same API work for other resources? How can I get details for SQL Server and Storage Account using same API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***You can use the below api's to get the required details :***

1. **Databases :**

   You can get ***SQL database*** `(serverless,single server etc.)` ,
   ***Database for PostgreSQL*** etc.

   ```
   https://prices.azure.com/api/retail/prices?api-version=2021-10-01-preview&$filter=serviceFamily eq 'Databases'
   ```

   [image]
2. **Storage Account:**

   This depends on what you want to create and store and the redundancy
   as well which is the same when you select from the drop down of
   ***[Pricing Calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/calculator/?OCID=AID2200195_SEM_c71a295463251b3976ad48e8f38f2401:G:s&ef_id=c71a295463251b3976ad48e8f38f2401:G:s&msclkid=c71a295463251b3976ad48e8f38f2401)***

   ```
   https://prices.azure.com/api/retail/prices?api-version=2021-10-01-preview&$filter=serviceFamily eq 'Storage'
   ```

   [image]